# how do I make public assets in Rails without using the assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I want to bypass the assets pipeline since a very, very silly processing error is completely preventing my app from working.

For example, I want to replace this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

with something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

How would I go about doing this? whenever I try to use this, the link just ends up pointing to a nonexistent .js file even if I actually put the file in public/javascripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove public, correct path is /javascripts/jquery.js.